# symfony 2.7 base bundle class not found in AppKernel

Tags: composer-php, symfony-2.7

I've created a symfony 2.7 bundle via the generator command and it got generated under src/Bundle/bundlename, however i want to use this bundle via composer to be able to use it in another project i moved the bundle files then created composer.json for the bundle

```
{
"name" : "extremesolution/payment-handler-vodafone-bundle",
"type" : "symfony-bundle",
"description": "Vodafone Redpoints Payment Handler Bundle",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Hazem Taha",
        "email": "hazem.taha@extremesolution.com"
    }
],
"require" : {
    "php": "^5.5"
},

"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~3.7"
},

"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Extremesolution\\Bundle\\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\\" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

and pushed it to a bitbucket private repo and required the bundle inside my project composer.json and provided the repository url and registered the bundle inside the AppKernel.php

> new Extremesolution\Bundle\PaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle()

however whenever i run composer update i get

> [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
>     Fatal error: Class 'Extremesolution\Bundle\PaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle' not found in /home/kan/symfony_
>     trials/payment-example/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
>     PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Extremesolution\Bundle\PaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle' not found in /home/kan/sym
>     fony_trials/payment-example/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
>     .

i'm using php version 5.5.38 via phpbrew, composer version 1.2.1, and symfony 2.7

am i missing anything ? is there a custom configuration for bundles to be used via composer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `composer.json` file, you configured the PSR-4 namespace prefix to be `Extremesolution\\Bundle\\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\\`. However, according to the error message, you are trying to load the class `Extremesolution\Bundle\PaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle\ExtremesolutionPaymentHandlerVodafoneBundle` (notice the missing `Extremesolution` part).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may come from the fact your package is on a private repository.
I suggest you change the visibility to public and publish it on packagist.

If for some reason you have to keep it private, have a look to the composer documentation on [how to handle private packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md).

Hope it may help,

regards